# Why random number in haskell using randomRIO giving error?

Tags: haskell, random

I am trying to print random number between 0 and 1 but the code is giving error. I'm unable to understand what am I doing wrong.

```
import System.Random
main = print (randomRIO (1,0))
```

> error:
> • No instance for (Show (IO a0)) arising from a use of ‘print’
> • In the expression: print (randomRIO (1, 0))
> In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (randomRIO (1, 0))   | 2 | main = print (randomRIO (1,0))   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> error:
> • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘randomRIO’
> prevents the constraint ‘(Random a0)’ from being solved.
> Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
> These potential instances exist:
> instance Random Integer -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
> instance Random Bool -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
> instance Random Char -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
> ...plus four others
> ...plus 29 instances involving out-of-scope types
> (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
> • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(randomRIO (1, 0))’
> In the expression: print (randomRIO (1, 0))
> In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (randomRIO (1, 0))
>
> error:
> • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘1’
> prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
> Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
> These potential instances exist:
> instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
> instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
> instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
> ...plus two others
> ...plus 35 instances involving out-of-scope types
> (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
> • In the expression: 1
> In the first argument of ‘randomRIO’, namely ‘(1, 0)’
> In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(randomRIO (1, 0))’   | 2 | main = print (randomRIO (1,0))   |                          ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Two</strike> Three problems:

```
print randomRIO (1,0)
```

Reads like the `print` function being given two arguments.  Or, more technically, since application is left associative, it means the same as this:

```
(print randomRIO) (1,0)
```

If you wanted to give `print` only one argument, you would have to parenthesize it:

```
print (randomIO (1,0))
```

But that brings us to our second problem.  `randomRIO` is an `IO` *action*, not a simple function.  Its type (specialized for educational purposes) is

```
randomRIO :: (Int, Int) -> IO Int
```

Notice that the return value is of the form `IO something`?  `randomRIO (1,0)` is an `IO Int`, but we want to print a plain `Int`.  To extract the `a` from an `IO a`, you *bind* the function to a variable in a `do` block:

```
main = do
    r <- randomRIO (1,0)
    print r
```

I thought that was it, but (if you don't do this in ghci like I did) you get an ambiguous type variable warning because `randomRIO` doesn't know whether you want to pick a random `Int` or a random `Double` or what, and simply printing it is not enough to deduce that.  So we have to specify:

```
main = do
    r <- randomRIO (1, 0)
    print (r :: Int)
```

(And come to think of it you probably wanted a `Double` anyway.)

We could have specified the type in a lot of different ways; on `r`, on the `1` or `0`, or using `r` in a way that makes its type clear.  Usually there are enough contextual clues in code that you don't need to annotate any expressions like this, as long as you annotate your top level functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but I am still getting error:  Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘randomRIO’

Comment: @RahulAgarwal ah oops, I tested in ghci which has special rules about that.  Fixed